# Заполнение TreeTable через дерево

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist

Я пытаюсь заполнить `TreeItems` из дерева, которое было собранно из БД вот таким вот кодом:

```
 public void HashMapInUsd(){
        TreeItem<ExpencesUSD> rootItem = new TreeItem(new ExpencesUSD("", "Данные", BigDecimal.ZERO));
        NodeBuilder branchesInf = new NodeBuilder();
        for (ExpencesUSD categoryBranches: branchesInf.getCategory()){
         TreeItem<ExpencesUSD> categoryBranchesItem = new TreeItem(categoryBranches);

for(ExpencesUSD additionalScoreBranches: categoryBranches.getChild()){
TreeItem<ExpencesUSD> additionalScoreItem = new 
TreeItem(additionalScoreBranches.getAdditional_score());
categoryBranchesItem.getChildren().add(additionalScoreItem);

for(ExpencesUSD scoreList: categoryBranches.getChild()){
TreeItem<ExpencesUSD> scoreListItem = new TreeItem(scoreList.getName_of_score());
           additionalScoreItem.getChildren().add(scoreListItem);
             }
         }
         rootItem.getChildren().add(categoryBranchesItem);
        }
        expences_usd.setRoot(rootItem);
```

Но результат, `TreeTable` не заполняется совсем, проверял дебагом, после начала `forEach(categoryEntry ->`
Все что находится внутри пропускается и выполнение сразу перепрыгивает к `rootItems.getChildren()`

Вот таким вот образом я создаю дерево из БД:

```
 public void arrayIn (){
        String arrayIn = "SELECT category, additional_score, name_score, defference FROM consolid";
 try {
     Connection arrayDate = DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection();
     PreparedStatement inf = arrayDate.prepareStatement(arrayIn);
     ResultSet rs = inf.executeQuery();
     while (rs.next()){
      String categoryDb = rs.getString(1);
      String additional_scoreDB = rs.getString(2);
      String scoreDb = rs.getString(3);
      BigDecimal differenceDb = new BigDecimal(rs.getString(4));
      boolean isCategoryExists = category.stream().anyMatch(u -> 
u.getCategory().equals(categoryDb));
      if(!isCategoryExists) {
      //Если категория не существует, то создаем ее в
      ExpencesUSD categoryEntry = new ExpencesUSD();
      categoryEntry.setCategory(categoryDb);
      category.add(categoryEntry);
                }
      boolean isAdditionalScoreExists = additional_score.stream().anyMatch(u -> 
u.getCategory().equals(additional_scoreDB));
      if(!isAdditionalScoreExists) {
      // Если additionalScore не существует, то добавляем ее в список.
      ExpencesUSD additionalScoreEntry = new ExpencesUSD();
     // Выставляем ей категорию, чтобы потом знать, к какой категории 
//additionalScore относится.
     additionalScoreEntry.setCategory(categoryDb);
     additionalScoreEntry.setAdditional_score(additional_scoreDB);
     additional_score.add(additionalScoreEntry);
      }
   // Score записываем в любом случае, так как и базы мы достаем 
//имено score записи.
                ExpencesUSD scoreEntry = new ExpencesUSD();
                scoreEntry.setCategory(categoryDb);
                scoreEntry.setAdditional_score(additional_scoreDB);
                scoreEntry.setName_of_score(scoreDb);
                scoreEntry.setTotalUsd(differenceDb);
                score.add(scoreEntry);
            }
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }

      for(ExpencesUSD additionalScoreEntry: additional_score) {
      // 1 шаг: находим категорию к которой относится текущий 
//additionalScoreEntry
     ExpencesUSD categoryEntry = category.stream().filter(c -> 
c.getCategory().equals(additionalScoreEntry.getCategory())).findFirst().get();
      // 2 шаг: Добавляем additionalScore к найденной категории.
            categoryEntry.getChild().add(additionalScoreEntry); categoryEntry.
setTotalUsd(categoryEntry.getTotalUsd().add(additionalScoreEntry.
getTotalUsd()));
        }
        for(ExpencesUSD scoreEntry: score) {
  // 1 шаг: сравниваем additional_score с additional_score из score
  ExpencesUSD additionalScoreEntry = additional_score.stream().filter(a -> 
a.getAdditional_score().equals(scoreEntry.getAdditional_score())).findFirst().get();
  // 2 шаг: Добавляем score к additional_score
  additionalScoreEntry.getChild().add(scoreEntry);
additionalScoreEntry.setTotalUsd(additionalScoreEntry.getTotalUsd().add(scoreEntry.getTotalUsd()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Поправьте пожалуйста ваш код, у вас комментарии поехали на строчку ниже, и он очень большой в длину строки, читать нереально.

Comment: Вообще код конечно кошмарный... Поясните, правильно ли я понял, что `ExpencesUSD` - содержит в себе дерево прочитанное из БД? Если да, то какова его структура? Можно показать основные положения этого класса (подозреваю, что он очень пространный - судя по стилю кодирования, конечно же)

Comment: Нет само дерево хранится в ArrayList<ExpencesUSD> category, в ExpencesUSD
геттеры и сеттеры ну и ArrayList childs для записывания в category детей

Comment: Примите совет, который к сути вопроса не относится, но всё же. Почитайте что-нибудь про стиль в программировании. Например, навскидку вспоминается, Мартин, "Чистый код". Здесь, на SO, просто не находится желающих читать ваш код (благо дело добровольное), а на работе в приличных местах за такой код наказывают (а скорее вообще не берут на работу).